# How to setState to a new object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React so maybe I'm approaching this wrong but I have an object containing an array in my state from the parent component (it's just hard coded dummy data for now) and I have a click handler on a button in a child component that when clicked, randomly shuffles/re-sorts that array and I want to re-render the items (via mapping) in the array on the page as soon as this happens.

When I do console.log of the new state, it logs the new state each time but it doesn't update/re-render the content on the page. What am I missing or doing wrong? Why won't my state update the items on the page?

I'm only including relevant parts of the code. I'm not including the shuffle function but just know that it works.

```
// From the parent component:

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        meals: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Pizza",
                ingredients: [
                    "dough",
                    "cheese",
                    "sauce"
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Pasta",
                ingredients: ["Pasta", "Sauce"]
            }
        ]
    });
}

// From the child component:

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        meals: props.meals
    };
    this.generateNewMealPlan = this.generateNewMealPlan.bind(this);
    this.shuffle = this.shuffle.bind(this);
}

shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
        temporaryValue,
        randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
        // Pick a remaining element...
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;

        // And swap it with the current element.
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}

generateNewMealPlan() {
    const newMeals = this.shuffle(this.props.meals);
    this.setState({ meals: newMeals }, function() {
      console.log(this.state.meals);
    });
}

render() {
    return (<button type="button" onClick={this.generateNewMealPlan}>Generate</button>);
}
```

Comment: What *"items on the page"*? All you have shown is rendering a button and nothing to do with rendering `state.meals`

Comment: I didn't think it was relevant to the issue to include here. I'm just passing state to a child component as props and mapping over that to render an unordered list of "meals" that shows the name and ingredients.

Comment: You need to do a comparison of previous state and new state and if they’re not the same then re render the component

Comment: What are you shuffling exactly, is it the meals or ingredients, also can you please add the shuffle code? your code looks fine, are you mapping the state or props?

Comment: @AaminKhan I added the shuffle function. I'm mapping the meals as props in a separate Meal component.

Comment: you should map to the state and not props, I have already created the codesandbox for you, request you to please update your question and add the mappings, I will write my answer after that, so that the community can be benefited :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are setting it to the `state` and mapping to the `props`. There are two ways react component re-renders

1. When a change occurs in the state
2. When there is a change in the props

In your case you are changing the state but the state has not been used in the render(as per the comment).
So other than mapping over the props you can do mapping over the state

```
//Child Render method
render = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.generateNewMealPlan()}>Generate</button>
        {this.state.meals.map((obj, index) => (
          <ul>
            <li>{obj.name}</li>
            {obj.ingredients.map((ing, ind) => (
              <small>{ing} </small>
            ))}
          </ul>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Here is the working solution to your problem https://codesandbox.io/s/qqqvll3686